# Drawing points in android based on predetermined points?

Tags: android, drawing

How I can draw on an Image View if I know the location of the points? I will have two arrays of values (x,y) I would like to draw a dot based on the two matching coordinates ( x[1] and y[1])

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a custom Imageview and draw a point in the override onDraw method.

[This](http://www.jayway.com/2012/07/03/creating-custom-android-views-part-2-how-padding-works-and-how-to-draw-your-own-content/) is a great tutorial, you could learn a lot from it.

Also [Drawing on top of an image in Android’s ImageView](http://joerg-richter.fuyosoft.com/?p=120).